# wrong/crazy number display in xpages dynamic view

Tags: xpages-extlib

I have a crazy effect when displaying in view with a number column in a dynamic view panel of an xPage: 
Some (not all!) entries are displayed like:
123.40000000000005

the value in the notes doc is 123.4 .

I cannot found any difference between that wrong displayed value and others, which are displayed correctly. 
I tried a few number formatting things in the column properties of the notes view: does not improve.

the notes view displayed everything well (for the notes client).

Is it a bug? Or did a forget some format settings for the dyn view control?

Thanks in advance, Uwe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a bug, more like a side effect.

Well because it is double, there is way to put floating point numbers in memory, sometimes it behaves "little bit strange" but its just a side effect. So there is sometimes small error in numbers.

read this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html
it explains how floating point works.

regards

Comment: so to get rid of this "side effect", I have to place a @formula (like @ToNumber(@Text(myValue)) into the column?

Regards - Uwe

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp:=yourfield;
@Round(tmp*100)/100
```

Comment: In a view column formulae 1. define a temporary var tmp with your field name, 2. return round (tmp * 100)/100 this will round to 2 digits after comma